# Derivative form of a Step Function

Tags: calculus, dirac-delta

I'm having some trouble understanding a equation in my Quantum Mechanics book.

I have a step function defined as 
$$\Psi(x) =    \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0 & x< -a \\
      N & -a\leq x< 0 \\
      -N & 0\leq x < a \\
      0 & x  \geq a \\
\end{array} 
\right.$$

The equation I'm struggling with is this:

$$\frac{d\Psi}{dx} = N \delta(x+a) -2N\delta(x) + N\delta(x-a)$$

I know that the derivative of the unit step function $U(x)$ is $\delta(x)$ but I don't see how to use this in the case of my step function (sorry for the dumb question)

Answer (score 1):

$\Psi(x)$ can be written as $N\,U(x+a) - 2N\,U(x) + N\,U(x-a).$ The given derivative follows directly from this.